# How to ensure all images load correctly

Tags: html, image, browser

In my HTML page I load about 40 images from the same domain (on page start up, all images load at same time). The problem is, sometimes some images don't show up, they're just a white box with a red X on the top left side. But if I try to refresh the page once (or a few times), that image then loads fine.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to ensure all images load fine?

Comment: 40 images is a lot to load, especially from the same domain - the overheads are going to be pretty high for most users and it is probably worth reconsidering if you can (eg. using image sprites).   However, if you are dead-set on it then it might be useful to provide some info on your internet connection, what server you are running it on, where that is based etc. - it could just be unreliability at one end or the other.  Are you able to check the server logs to see if the requests made it through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the images aren't finished loading in time. You could try [pre-loading them with javascript](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/images/preloading.html)

What I would do is make sure the images are small (using thumbnails) so they will load.  Then, load only a few at a time and load more as the page is scrolled or whenever the user requests more images.

See google images or pinterest for an example of how it would work.  As you scroll the page, more images are loaded, as opposed to loading them all at once.

Comment: whats this difference between this and loading the images using <img src=""> tag?

Comment: There is virtually no difference since they both put the image in the cache, except with javascript you can put the image in the cache before you need it.  It isn't really needed in your instance since your needing them to be loaded on the home page and not just a sub page.  The best bet is to make sure you're loading thumbnails and not full sized images and progressively load them as the user requests them.